# Insert values of a form into last row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my form to add its values to a new row in a table right below the last used row. this is what I got:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

    If MiemCombx.Value = "General" Then
    Sh = Sheets("General")
    lastrow = sh.UsedRange.Row - 1 + sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 1) = Nume
        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 2) = Date
        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 3) = MiemCombx
        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 4) = ClasCombx
        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 5) = ConcTxt
        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 6) = JustCombx
        Sh.Cells(lastrow, 7) = Impo

    End If
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you coded?  What result are you getting?  Please see "How to Ask" and Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Also, see the help center for more information about what's on-topic on this site. You can edit your question to provide more information as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this, here's one based upon the last appearance of a value in column A:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim c as Range

Set sh = sheets("General")
Set c = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)

c.Offset(1, 1) = Nume
c.Offset(1, 2) = Date
c.Offset(1, 3) = MiemCombx
c.Offset(1, 5) = ConcTxt
c.Offset(1, 6) = JustCombx
c.Offset(1, 7) = Impo

End Sub
```

Or, if you prefer using 'lastrow', then

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim lastrow as Long

Set sh = sheets("General")
Set lastrow = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

sh.Cells(lastrow , 1) = Nume
sh.Cells(lastrow , 2) = Date
sh.Cells(lastrow , 3) = MiemCombx
sh.Cells(lastrow , 5) = ConcTxt
sh.Cells(lastrow , 6) = JustCombx
sh.Cells(lastrow , 7) = Impo

End Sub
```

Hope one works for you.